# How to convert php5 cgi to module?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi, cgi

I installed PHP5 on my debian lenny system as cgi. Now I found that flush() in php is only working for php installed as module.
Anyone know how to (re)install php5 as module? (apache2)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy and paste the following.

```
sudo -i
aptitude -y remove php5-cgi
aptitude -y install libapache2-mod-php5
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and it should be done. You will be asked for a password.